# Error downloading file in Android default browser, java.io.IOException: Write failure

Tags: java, android, file, browser, download

I have .apk file in my resources dir and I want to download it directly from Mobile devices.

All is fine when using Chrome, or when I try it in my PC, but when using default Android Browser I get a .htm file and a:

> ClientAbortException:  java.io.IOException: Write failure

I dont understand what is happens or if it´s a browser´s bug.

Exception thrown after some loops in:

> out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);

Any suggestions? Thanks!

This is my code:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String download(@ModelAttribute("apkDownload") @Valid ApkDownloadDTO apkDownload, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, BindingResult result) {


InputStream is = ApkDownloadController.class.getResourceAsStream("/apk/mine.apk");


try {

    response.addHeader("Content-Description", "File Transfer");
    response.addHeader("Content-Type", " application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=mine.apk");
    response.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");

    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];

    while (is.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1) {
    out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
    }
    is.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error(e);
} finally {
    try {
    is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    log.error(e);
    }
}
return null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using some other browser other then default browser,
e.g UC Browser, Chrome, etc
You'll get to known then if its default browser problem or not

Comment: I wrote "All is fine when using Chrome, or when I try it in my PC..." :D But i dont know if I must use different way to send the file or is a bug :S
Thanks for reply ^^

Comment: Yes, tried in 3 different devices :S 
Android default browser from 4.1.2 and 4.2.2

Comment: Yes Ajinkya :S I will try if possible with another Android versions.